# Carousel didn't start cycle onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Problem is in title.

My html:

```
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item"><%=  image_tag("/images/home_page_1.png")%></div>
      <div class="item"><%= image_tag("/images/home_page_2.png", :size => '600x260') %></div>
      <div class="item"><%= image_tag("/images/home_page_3.png", :size => '600x260') %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My js:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 200 })
```

Files are in my js folder. Everthing else working wright.
Google chrome gives me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel' :3000/assets/application.js?body=1:17

Comment: Does "Everthing else working wright." mean that jQuery has been loaded successfully? Are other jQuery functions working? Which Carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: please post your website link

Comment: Yes, I'm using other Bootstrap javascript and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure:

- Only one jQuery is loaded.
- jQuery is included before `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap-carousel.js`
- Don't include both `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-carousel.js`

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded your jquery carousel extension javascript file correctly? Jquery does not have carousel method by default, you have to use extension like http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm